# Rspec Best Practices : Why should "it" expect only one thing?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, bdd

I read on this slide about RSpec best practices ( http://blog.bandzarewicz.com/slides/krug-the-perfect-rspec/#19 ) and many other places , that it is best practice to have only one expectation with one "it" . For example :

```
describe UsersController, '#create' do
  # setup spec...
  it 'creates a new user' do
    should assign_to(:user).with(user)
    should set_the_flash
    should respond_with(:redirect)
    should redirect_to(admin_user_path(user))
  end
end
```

## vs.

```
describe UsersController, '#create' do
  # setup spec...
  it { should assign_to(:user).with(user) }
  it { should set_the_flash }
  it { should respond_with(:redirect) }
  it { should redirect_to(admin_user_path(user)) }
end
```

Why is it best practise to have only one expectation with one "it" ?

Comment: Well, "Unit testing" is a self explanatory expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because this approach is better for documentation. Try `rspec --format documentation`. And another reason, with one `should` per `it`, you can always see which test is failing.

Comment: I didn't think about the documentation output . Thank you .